# RApache get Query String from executing URL - howto?

Tags: apache2, querystring

I would like to get the query string from the executing URL into my R. I've installed and configured R Apache. Everything works to this extend.

My R code so far is:

```
query_string <- Sys.getenv("QUERY_STRING")
cat("Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
cat("Die Anfrage-URL ist:", query_string)
```

I get no information from QUERY_STRING. Why? Any tipps and tricks?

My executing URL is http://localhost/R/query.R?query=hello

I would like to extract "hello".

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there is a far more simpler approach.

Just use GET, POST, COOKIES, FILES or SERVER.

When using RApache, you get GET, POST, COOKIES, FILES, SERVER variables which are passed on to the script.

```
args <- GET
 
print(args[1])
print(args[2])
print(args[3])
```

> http://[ip address]/R/query.R?query=people&word=hello&verb=Simon